# Direct URL link to a simple modal JQuery popup

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I am looking to see if it is possible to have a direct hyper link to a simple modal. i.e `domain.com#modal`. I have tried the below line (which is part of simple modal that works on existing page only.

```
    <a href="#" class="osx_contact" id="contact">Demo</a>
```

As you can see there is no href... I think it is because of the class and the tag.

But when I make a hyperlink with `ID="contact"`. it will not open the simple modal :(

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies in the JavaScript being used to bind the modal function.

With the example you provided, there are a number of ways in which the modal open function could be bound...element, class, id or any combination of those.

So, check to see how the modal function is being bound in the JavaScript and then modify your markup accordingly...or vice versa.